# Restangular: impossible to post complex json parameters?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, restangular

I would like to send complex json to a put route:

```
    Restangular.one('model3ds', model.uuid).put(
       api_key: "blabla"
       model3d: { is_public: true }
    )
```

But it does not seems possible with Restangular, since it send:

```
api_key: "blabla"
model3d: "{\"is_public:\":true}"
```

Anyone knows how to change this behavior ?

Note: I can do that, but it's not possible if i have a full object to send, not only a property.

```
    Restangular.one('model3ds', model.uuid).put(
        "model3d[is_public]": true
    )
```

Comment: By *complex* json do you mean sending JavaScript expressions in json?

Comment: I mean something more than a simple hash, like a hash of hashes: { par1: val1, par2: { subpar2: val2 } }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I found the (very complicated !) answer:
All the magic is in the custom keyword ;)

```
Restangular.one('model3ds', model.uuid).customPUT(
   api_key: "blabla"
   model3d: { is_public: true }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way without using `customPUT` is to provide the object as the second parameter of `put` method. For example:

```
var object = {
    api_key: "blabla"
    model3d: { is_public: true }
};
Restangular.one('model3ds', model.uuid).put(null, object);
```

More info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17184167/1852787