# restangular all().post() does not return an object?

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have been trying to use restangular post(), but am failing to get the response of the post returned in the promise:

```
var reports = Restangular.all('reports');
reports.post($scope.formData).then(function(newRecord) {
  console.log(newRecord);
});
```

The `console.log()` returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?
Checking the response data shows that I am getting a valid json string back as a response:

```
{"reportId":"34","type":"Group","outputMode":"store","huh":"someOutputData","magic":"someOutputFormatting"}
```

Firebug knows how to crunch the above into a valid json object.

I'm using restangular min 1.4.0.

Thanks for any help!

Note: Among the other restangular questions I've looked at, I also have seen [question 17135998](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135998/getting-response-from-restangular-post), and it does not solve my issue. In fact, if you look at the comment by paynestrike, it seems that he/she encounters the same issue with a kind of all().post() only returning `undefined`.

**EDIT:**

I have also tried putting in a second callback into `then()` to see if I am getting an error (also in question 17135998) but I do not seem to be getting any.

Comment: Can you add a second function callback to the .then() function to see if an error is occurring somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that too, but I do not get thrown into the second callback. Are you able to get all().post() to return something for you?

Comment: Okay, nevermind. We were being messed up by our own code. Somewhere else in the code was a `setResponseExtractor` that was not done properly: In the event that no processing happened, it was returning `response.data` instead of just `response`, so since the key `'data'` didn't exist, `undefined` was being returned.

Comment: I had the same issue using Spring Data Rest on the server side. In my case all I had to do was to add into config: `RepositoryRestConfiguration.setReturnBodyOnCreate(true)`